# pgfkey containing a foreach statement with a variable number of values

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to use pgfkeys in a macro. One key contains a foreach statement which handles a variable number of values. I have some problems concerning the right order of the output. Here a simplified example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
/test/.is family,
/test/.cd,
    key a/.store in = \keyA,
    key a print/.code = \texttt{\keyA},
    key b/.code = {\foreach \x in {#1}{\textbf{\x}--}}
}%

\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\pgfkeys{/test, #1, key a print}}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{key a = valueKeyA, key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}}
\end{document}
```

The order of the output is: valueKeyB1–valueKeyB2–valueKeyB3–valueKeyA

How can I achieve that valueKeyA is typeset first? If I put #1 at the end of the key list in my example code I get an error message. If I place it at the end of the key list in my actual code the values of the first keys are missing. I guess it has either something to do with the order in which the values are stored and the keys are executed or my use of #1 is mixed up.

I am using pgfkeys for a short time and would be glad if someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, the keys are executed in the following order:

1. `key a = valueKeyA`. This stores `valueKeyA` in the macro `\keyA`.
2. `key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}`.  This prints out `valueKeyB1--valueKeyB2--valueKeyB3--` (ignoring formatting)
3. `key a print`. This prints out `\keyA` which expands to `valueKeyA`.

So the problem is that for `key a`, the processing is split into two parts: storing and printing, whilst for `key b` this is all done in one step.  The order in which you call things means that the two steps for `a` are split by the one step for `b`.  There are a variety of ways to fix this depending on what you want to achieve.

Before giving some, let me explain why putting `#1` at the end doesn't work.  This is because that puts step 3 above *first*, whereupon it tries to print out the value of `\keyA` which hasn't been set yet.

As I said, how to fix this depends on what you want to do in your real code.  Here are a couple.

1. Put the `key a print` inside the argument to `\mymacro` in the right place, so we have:

   ```
   \newcommand\mymacro[1]{\pgfkeys{/test, #1}}

   \begin{document}
   \mymacro{key a = valueKeyA, key a print, key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}}
   ```
2. Make the `key a` step both store and print its value, something like:

   ```
   \pgfkeys{/test/.cd, key a/.code={\def\keyA{#1}\texttt{#1}}}
   ```

   Then remove `key a print` from everywhere.
3. Make the `key b` step store its result in a macro to be printed out later.  Something like:

   ```
   \pgfkeys{/test/.cd, key b/.code={\def\keyB{}\foreach \x in {#1}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\keyB\expandafter{\keyB\textbf{\x}--}}}, key b print/.code={\keyB}}
   ```

   Then add `key b print` after `key a print` (or do a combined `print all keys`).

There are probably more - even if those don't prove to be useful they should help you figure out what features of a solution you would like.

---

(*Edit: 2013-06-20*)

The third solution has a little issue with expansion.  The `\x` needs to be expanded at least once within the definition of `\keyB`.  If everything can be expanded at definition time, then this can be achieved with a `\protected@xdef` instead of the `\gdef`.  If not, then it's a slew of `\expandafter`s.

Seriously, LaTeX3 is **so** much easier for this sort of thing, so I've added a LaTeX3 version that keeps pretty close to the PGF foreach one (the minor difference being that I iterate over the key list at display time not at definition time).  I would probably do it slightly differently in that I wouldn't bother having the `key a print` and `key b print` as keys but just as commands.  But I'm staying close to your code so that you can see the similarities and differences.

The following all produce:

> `valueKeyA`**valueKeyB1**--**valueKeyB2**--**valueKeyB3**

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54533/86}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\pgfkeys{%
/test/.is family,
/test/.cd,
    key a/.store in = \keyA,
    key a print/.code = \texttt{\keyA},
    key b/.code = {%
      \let\keyB=\relax%
      \foreach \x in {#1} {%
        \ifx\keyB\relax
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\keyB\expandafter{\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\x}}%
        \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\keyB\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
          \expandafter\keyB\expandafter-\expandafter-\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\x}%
        }%
        \fi
      }%
    },
    key b print/.code={\keyB}
}%

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
/xtest/.is family,
/xtest/.cd,
    key a/.store in = \keyA,
    key a print/.code = \texttt{\keyA},
    key b/.code = {%
      \let\keyB=\relax%
      \foreach \x in {#1} {%
        \ifx\keyB\relax
        \protected@xdef\keyB{\protect\textbf{\x}}%
        \else
        \protected@xdef\keyB{%
          \keyB--\protect\textbf{\x}%
        }%
        \fi
      }%
    },
    key b print/.code={\keyB}
}%
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__aik_keya_tl
\clist_new:N \l__aik_keyb_clist
\keys_define:nn {3test}
{
  key~ a .tl_set:N = \l__aik_keya_tl,
  key~ b .clist_set:N = \l__aik_keyb_clist,
  key~ a~ print .code:n = {
    \texttt{\tl_use:N \l__aik_keya_tl}
  },
  key~ b~ print .code:n = {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__aik_keyb_clist
    {
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl \textbf{##1}
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {--}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \mytmacro {m}
{
  \keys_set:nn {3test} {#1, key~ a~ print, key~ b~ print}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\pgfkeys{/test, #1, key a print, key b print}}
\newcommand\myxmacro[1]{\pgfkeys{/xtest, #1, key a print, key b print}}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{key a = valueKeyA, key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}}

\myxmacro{key a = valueKeyA, key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}}

\mytmacro{key a = valueKeyA, key b = {valueKeyB1, valueKeyB2, valueKeyB3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The order in which the different steps are achieved is quiet what I expected. I did even try something like you suggest in your third solution, but obviously I made a mistake. The second way works fine for me and keeps everything simple, which is a good thing...

Comment: In case the value stored in `\keyA` is used in the code of several keys which are supposed to deliver different outputs, the third solution would be better. So out of interest i tried to solve the problem this way, too. If I use the code of your third suggestion a long dash (for the three en dashes in the example) is printed, but the values (valueKeyB1-3) are missing. Do you know why the values are not printed? I roughly understand your trick but not well enough to fix this.

Comment: @Aik I will confess to posting this without actually trying out the code.  I will take another look at the third version and see what went wrong.

Comment: It has been a while since I posted this question and I really want to accept your answer. It would be nice if you find the time to take a look at the third solution. You are doing great work here at TeX SE!

Comment: @Aik My apologies!  I appear to have completely forgotten this.  I hope that my update goes some way to mitigate this.

Comment: No need for an apology! You already offered two solutions! Thanks for the edit and your plea for LaTeX3, I will familiarize myself with it.